# When adding a new query in Django, the foreign key gets the value NULL

Tags: django, sqlite

I am still learning programming and currently experimenting with Django.

Currently I am trying to build a task manager but when I try to add a new **Tasks**(def new_tasks) it should be related to **TaskGroup**, instead the task_group_id is related to NULL and I can't seem to figure out why. I believe the reason is some where in the views.py -> def new_tasks. Any help is gratefully appreciated.

The structure:

```
 Project 1
    Task Group 1
        Tasks 1
            Task 1
            Task 2
            Task 3
        Tasks 2
            Task 4
            Task 5
    Task Group 2
        Tasks 3
            Task 6
Project 2
    Task Group 3
        Tasks 4
            Task 7
            Task 8
```

Relating the Task Group to Project works but relating the Tasks to Task Group gives the value NUll.
[image of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fydyW.png)

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Project(models.Model):
    """A project the user is working on."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text


class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    """ Title of a group of tasks """
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """ Return a string representation of the model. """
        return self.title


class Tasks(models.Model):
    """ Will be the title/segment that will contain the task items """
    task_group = models.ForeignKey(TaskGroup, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """ Return a string representation of the model. """
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Project, TaskGroup, Task, Tasks
from .forms import ProjectForm, TasksForm, TaskGroupForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import Http404
from django.contrib import messages
# Delete
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.urls import reverse


@login_required
def taskgroup(request, task_id):
    """Show a single task"""
    taskgroup = TaskGroup.objects.get(id=task_id)
    tasks = taskgroup.tasks_set.all()



    # Make sure the task belongs to the current user.
    project = taskgroup.project
    if project.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    context = {'taskgroup':taskgroup, 'tasks': tasks}
    return render(request, 'tasks/taskgroup.html', context)


@login_required
def task(request, task_id):
    """Show a single task"""
    tasks = Task.objects.get(id=task_id)

    # Make sure the task belongs to the current user.
    project = tasks.project
    if project.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    context = {'tasks':tasks}
    return render(request, 'tasks/task.html', context)

@login_required
def new_project(request):
    """Add new project"""

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = ProjectForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = ProjectForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_project = form.save(commit=False)
            new_project.owner = request.user
            new_project.save()
            return redirect('tasks:projects')

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'tasks/new_project.html', context)


@login_required
def new_taskgroup(request, project_id):
    """ Add new task """
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)

    # Make sure the task belongs to the current user.
    if project.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TaskGroupForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TaskGroupForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_taskgroup = form.save(commit=False)
            new_taskgroup.project = project
            new_taskgroup.save() 
            return redirect('tasks:project', project_id=project_id)

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'project': project, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'tasks/new_taskgroup.html', context)


@login_required
def new_tasks(request, taskgroup_id):
    """ Add new task """
    taskgroup = TaskGroup.objects.get(id=taskgroup_id)
    

    
    # Make sure the task belongs to the current user.
    project = taskgroup.project
    if project.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TasksForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TasksForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_tasks = form.save(commit=False)
            new_tasks.taskgroup = taskgroup
            new_tasks.save() 
            return redirect('tasks:taskgroup', task_id=taskgroup_id)


    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'taskgroup': taskgroup, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'tasks/new_tasks.html', context)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project, TaskGroup, Task, Tasks

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}

class TaskGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskGroup
        fields = ['title', 'desc']
        labels = {'desc': 'Description:','title': 'Title:'}
        widgets = {'desc': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':80})}


class TasksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ['title']
        labels = {'title': 'title:'}
```

**urls.py**

```
"""Defines URL patterns for tasks"""

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'tasks'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # Page that shows all projects.
    path('taskmanager/', views.projects, name='projects'),
    # Detail page for a single project.
    path('taskmanager/<int:project_id>/', views.project, name='project'),
    # Detail page for a single taskgroup.
    path('taskmanager/task/<int:task_id>/', views.taskgroup, name='taskgroup'),
    # Detail page for a single task.
    path('taskmanager/task/<int:task_id>/', views.task, name='task'),
    # Page for adding a new project
    path('new_project/', views.new_project, name='new_project'),
    # Page for adding new task group
    path('new_taskgroup/<int:project_id>/', views.new_taskgroup, name='new_taskgroup'),
    # Page for adding new task
    path('new_tasks/<int:taskgroup_id>/', views.new_tasks, name='new_tasks'),
    # Page for editing task
    path('edit_task/<int:task_id>/', views.edit_task, name='edit_task'),
]

urlpatterns.extend(
    [
        path('delete/<int:task_id>/', views.delete_task, name='delete_task'),
    ]
)
```

Comment: The `ForeignKey` has an underscore in it: `new_tasks.task_group = taskgroup`

Comment: Goddamn, you are a hero and I'm an idiot. It was just that, thanks, really appreciate the help!:)

Answer (score 1):

Made a Mistake, fixed it.
`new_tasks.taskgroup = taskgroup` => `new_tasks.task_group = taskgroup`
thanks to Iain!